# Delphi 10.4 [PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: exportArchive: Provisioning profile "**" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution: **"

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, provisioning

At dev Apple portal i create all certificate:

- my iOs distribute
- AppId
- Provision Profile

In XCode I create simple app with the same BundleID. And i see certificate normaly.
But Delphi 10.4 dont see signing certificate.

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2021-11-01 18:58:12.370 xcodebuild[16327:1202645] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/hj/f9ghw_0517zbkpp54l0fzk6w0000gn/T/AA.BB.CCCCCCC_2021-11-01_18-58-12.370.xcdistributionlogs'.
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: exportArchive: Provisioning profile "*******_PP" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution: MYNAME (G1234567890)".
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 Error Domain=IDEProfileQualificationErrorDomain Code=5 "Provisioning profile "*******_PP" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution: MYNAME (G1234567890)"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Provisioning profile "*******_PP" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution: MYNAME (G1234567890)"., IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, IDEProfileQualificationError_MissingCerts={(
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fe14de74960; name='Apple Distribution: MYNAME (G1234567890)', hash='3A30204A02891B49500BF2B2F2DD9*********', serialNumber='<DVTSigningCertificateSerialNumber: 0x*********>', certificateKinds='(
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4",
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.7"
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ), issueDate='2021-10-29 12:18:01 +0000''>
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 )}, IDEProfileQualificationError_Profile=<IDEEmbeddedProvisioningProfile 0x7fe148d05850: name: *******_PP, UUID: *******-cc92-4ef6-9f94-a021d4a3c6d8, teamName: MYNAME, teamIdentifierPrefixes: (
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     G1234567890
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ), entitlements: {
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "application-identifier" = "G1234567890.AA.BB.CCCCCCC";
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "beta-reports-active" = 1;
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "com.apple.developer.team-identifier" = G1234567890;
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "get-task-allow" = 0;
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "keychain-access-groups" =     (
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776         "G1234567890.*",
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776         "com.apple.token"
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     );
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 }, appIdentifierName: *******, applicationIdentifierPrefixes: (
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     G1234567890
******
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ** EXPORT FAILED **
```

Comment: You don't mention whether you actually download the certificate, or the provisioning profiles, to the Mac

Comment: I recreate all certificate and got next error :(

Comment: What next error? You need to update your question with the new information